# show on button clicked doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making a simple app. When I press a button, a `Fragment` has to appear in the `MainActivity` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
package org.escoladeltreball.firstassignment;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  BlankFragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private Button btn_fragmentA, brn_fragmentB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        btn_fragmentA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fragmentA);
        brn_fragmentB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fragmentB);

        btn_fragmentA.setOnClickListener(v -> addFragmentA());
    }

    private void addFragmentA() {

        Fragment blankFragmentA=new BlankFragmentA();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.fragment_container,blankFragmentA).
                addToBackStack(null).
                commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the button it doesn't do anything. If I change the code of `addFragmentA()` to make a simple `Toast`, it works perfectly.

Here are the fragmentactivity.java

```
package org.escoladeltreball.firstassignment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragmentA#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragmentA extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public BlankFragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragmentA.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragmentA newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragmentA fragment = new BlankFragmentA();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Here are the layout files:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.escoladeltreball.firstassignment.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_fragmentA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/btn_fragmentA" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_fragmentB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/btn_fragmentB" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_blank.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.escoladeltreball.firstassignment.BlankFragmentA">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_fragmentA_tittle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/txt_fragmentA_tittle" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using a `FragmentManager` and a `ViewPager`?

Comment: Show your layout files for fragment and activity.

Comment: Added all the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `0dp` for `width` and `height`. Make it `match_parent`. Change your top `LinearLayout` of `activity_main.xml`. Instead of -

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Use -

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also change `height` to `wrap_content`  of second level `LinearLayout` of your `activity_main.xml`. I mean `LinearLayout` of you `Button` container.

Comment: Also change `height` to `wrap_content`  of second level `LinearLayout` of your `activity_main.xml`. I mean `LinearLayout` of you `Button` container.

Comment: Okay, that was the problem, any idea why the fragment didn't show up?

Comment: When you use `match_parent` as `width` or `height` for any view, It takes whole dimension of parent view.So your button container took all space of parent layout. Thats why your  `Fragment` container was not shown. But `wrap_content` takes only required space for its content. So remaining space can be used for further view. Read more about it - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

The Area you providing to your container is 0 in height as the above LInearlayout already got all the height as match parent. Try to remove that layout or put both linearlayout inside relativelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.escoladeltreball.firstassignment.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_fragmentA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_fragmentA" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_fragmentB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_fragmentB" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```